# How to write regex that excludes the name after Mr. when finding words at the start of a sentence?

Tags: regex

I currently have to make a regex that matches the first words at the start of sentences. I've currently done to the point where it matches the first word at the start of the paragraph and the rest, the first words that come after ". The problem that I have here is that 'Sherwood' which is obviously a name, shouldn't be matched but is because it matches the regex which I have written. 'Capital starting letter, comes directly after . and a space'

How can I change my code to exclude the name that comes after Mr. or Dr.?

Current regex: `((^[A-Z]+[a-z]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*|(?<=\")[A-Z]+[a-z]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*)|(?<=\.\s)[A-Z]+[a-z]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*)`

I've used [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) as a reference.

Comment: You can use a negative lookbehind: `(?<!(Mr|Dr)\. )REST_OF_YOUR_REGEX`.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the pattern with the alternations to a single non capture group containing the 3 patterns that are allowed for the start of the string.

As you are already using a lookbehind assertion, you can exclude Mr. of Dr. to the left using a negative lookbehind:

```
(?:^|(?<=")|(?<=\.\s))(?<![MD]r\. )[A-Z]+[a-z]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R3PByY/1)

You might also first match an uppercase char, and then do the assertions to prevent the alternation with the lookbehind assertions to fire on every position when there is no match.

```
[A-Z](?<=".|\.\s.|^.)(?<![MD]r\. .)(?:[A-Z]*[a-z]*){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJHAUM/1)

Comment: What is the reason of the last `[A-Z]*[a-z]*`?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan It is in the pattern of the OP, it matches optional uppercase followed by optional lowercase characters

Comment: I know what it does, but it can work also without that. Just `(?:^|(?<=")|(?<=\.\s))(?<![MD]r\. )[A-Z]+[a-z]*` I mean.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan It can, but it is not the same. I will then for example match a single `Test` in `TestTest`

Comment: Then it can also be `TestTestTest` or `TestTestTestTest`

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I used what the OP has in the pattern. You can write it as `[A-Z][A-Za-z]*` or `(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)+` or how specific you want it to be.